# What is wrong with this set up for unit tests using nhibernate and an in-memory sqlite db?

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

I have an app written in c# using nhibernate with an sqlite DB. For unit testing, I'm using xunit and an in-memory sqlite db.

I'm aware that the in-memory DB is destroyed when the session is closed so for testing, I use a single session and keep it open for the duration of the test. In most of my tests this works fine.

However, in a few cases, I need to test methods that make use of both `ISession` and `IStatelessSession`. After a little research, I settled on something similar to the approach described [here](http://hotgazpacho.org/2012/03/testing-with-nhibernate-in-memory/). So the `IStatelessSession` is created using the `ISession`'s connection like this:

```
statelessSession = factory.OpenStatelessSession(existingSession.Connection);
```

The problem is that this seems to cause some sort of conflict as soon as a change is persisted to the DB. If I do a transaction with `session.SaveOrUpdate(new Entity() {...})` then that's fine but if I then do a `statelessSession.Get<Entity>(1)` then it will fail with the error message "collection is not associated with any session".

Normally, this error would indicate that the session is closed, but in this case, both sessions are still open and active.

If I do `session.Get<Entity>(1)` then it returns the entity as expected. Initially, I thought this might be because the session and stateless session were somehow out of sync so I replaced `session.SaveOrUpdate..` with `statelessSession.Insert(new Entity() {...})` and reran the test. Strangely, this made no difference. The regular session still works fine and the statelessSession is still broken.

Comment: Where do you flush the session and/or commit the transaction?

Comment: @OskarBerggren I have a data access base class that includes several methods taking an `Action<ISession>` or `Action<IStatelessSession>`. These methods handle all the transaction related stuff. However, I think you may be on to something. I have a suspicion that the methods for IStatelssSession doe not handle the transaction in the same way and there might be a problem in there. Will investigate and report back later..

Comment: What I'm aiming at is that if you close commit the transaction, the session will close the connection and not care (or even know) that the stateless session is using the same connection.

Comment: @OskarBerggren Sadly, I still can't find the problem. Both the regular and stateless sessions are definitely still open and active. I've had a look at the logic for handling the transaction for stateless session but it all looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution to this whole thing:

Eventually, I went back to my original query (a more complex query than the example above that returns multiple results) and tried various things while debugging through it, none of which shed any light on the problem.
I then decided to remove the 'where' part of that query to see if it made any difference. Strangely, it did. 
It still failed, but this time I got a different exception: 'could not execute query', this also had an inner exception: 'possible non-threadsafe access to the session'.

The whole test runs on a single thread and I confirmed this by looking at the thread view when debugging. So I thought I'd hit another brick wall. However, after some googling, I found [this blog post](http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/nhibernate-error-possible-non.html) that describes the same problem and the solution: just update to the latest version of nhibernate!

I updated from 3.1.0 to 3.3.1 (thanks to NUGet, this was a breeze) re ran the test and it worked. Put the where clause back and the test passed.